# Why are Pakistani and Turkish students pretending to be Indians to flee Ukraine?

Tags: armed-conflict, india, ukraine

There [are](https://www.ibtimes.com/pakistani-turkish-students-flee-ukraine-under-indian-flags-amid-brutal-russian-3420510) [reports](https://youtu.be/XzTRZuA-T9E) of [Pakistani](https://youtu.be/x9VMbBS6C3Q) and [Turkish](https://www.newindianexpress.com/world/2022/mar/02/pakistani-turkish-students-use-indian-flag-to-flee-from-ukraine-2425416.html) [students](https://youtu.be/su69NaA--lo) [using the Indian Flag](https://youtu.be/wGR3MghFHIY) to flee out of the war in Ukraine. Why are they not able to use the flags of their native countries to flee of out of Ukraine?

Comment: I'm not sure the flags are helping at all, there is a huge effort to accept refugees from Ukraine and it sounds like these people received that hospitality and also happened to have an Indian flag. It isn't necessarily cause and effect.

Comment: Each and every reference you posted are from India. Do you have any other references from any other country?  If this question is only on the basis of Indian news, then this question will get a heavy bashing along with rational arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that they were following some advice recommending to carry the flag of a supposedly Russian-friendly country in order to avoid being targeted by Russian attacks.

Similarly, Chinese nationals were originally [advised by their ambassy](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/mar/08/chinese-students-fled-ukraine-condemn-embassy-response) to display the Chinese flag. The advice was rescinded the next day:

> “This is exactly what happened when the embassy rescinded its previous advice after realising how negatively an expressive pro-Russia position is viewed by the Ukrainians and the international community, which was apparently not considered at all when it hastily issued its first advice.”

Comment: Pakistan was recently even more friendly to Russia than India. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voFkiKj3nIs So substituting the Pakistani for the Indian flag doesn't make much sense in this context.

Comment: It so happened that Khan was visiting Moscow on the day of the invasion, by the way. https://www.voanews.com/a/pakistan-walks-thin-line-between-russia-ukraine-/6469614.html

Comment: @Fizz, It's not about Russia, it's about Ukraine. Eastern European Slavic countries are not known to be very polite to helpless Muslim foreigners.

Comment: @user366312: I suppose that's a more valid point that them trying to pass as non-Muslim might have been the angle, assuming the story is true. There is one story like that in the US, some 12 years ago https://www.reuters.com/article/us-timessquare-backlash-idUSTRE64655Y20100507 The circumstances were pretty different though.

Answer (score 3):

The story appears to be of dubious origin, [e.g.](https://www.opindia.com/2022/03/pakistan-embassy-algeria-students-ukraine-indian-flag/):

> the Pakistan Embassy in Algeria suggested that the country should ask for financial aid from India as it is failing to provide help to its nationals stranded in Ukraine.
>
> “Embassies ordered to divert funds to Ukraine for evacuating Pakistani Nationals. Should we also start asking funds from India as Pakistan Nationals are using Indian flags to flee from Ukraine”, the Pakistan Embassy in Algeria tweeted. It also said that till date no Pakistani national was evacuated and nor did it have funds to pay salaries to its officials or to help Pakistani nationals stranded in Ukraine.
>
> The embassy in Algeria stated that they have been asked by their government to divert funds so that students in Ukraine can be evacuated. They asserted that they do not have funds to even pay salaries to their staff members.
>
> **However, the tweet was later deleted after the Foreign Office of Pakistan stated that the social media accounts of Pakistan’s embassy in Algeria had been “hacked” and the posts did not belong to the mission.**

It's not terribly sure that the hack happened, but it seem even some the Indian press is casting doubt on the claim(s).

And another [story debunked](https://theprint.in/hoaxposed/social-media-ridicules-pakistani-students-for-using-tricolour-in-ukraine-they-are-actually-indians/858390/):

> Social media ridicules ‘Pakistani students’ for using tricolour in Ukraine. They are actually Indians
>
> A wrong photo has proliferated social media, giving ammunition to Indian users to take a dig at Pakistan.

And while that story insists that some reports, e.g. by NDTV are true (and used the correct picture), reading/finding [one of these](https://www.ndtv.com/world-news/russia-ukraine-war-russia-ukraine-airlift-spray-painted-curtain-india-flag-helps-pak-turkey-students-flee-ukraine-2798181) reveals that the claims are from Indian students.

> The Indian students who arrived in the city of Bucharest in Romania from Ukraine said that the national tricolour helped them as well as some Pakistani and Turkish students in safely crossing the various checkpoints in the war-torn country. [...]
>
> They added that even some Pakistani and Turkish students passed checkpoints using the Indian flag.
>
> "The Turkish and Pakistani students were also using the Indian flag," a student said, adding that the Indian flag was of great help to the Pakistani, Turkish students.

What seems to be lacking are first-hand accounts from such Pakistani or Turkish students.

Frankly, I find it most improbable Turkish students would have done that. Because e.g. [it appears](http://mae.ro/en/node/3782) that Romania and Turkey have a no-visa-needed arrangement, for tourists at least.

On the other hand, [there are](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/russia-ukraine-war/turkish-student-evacuated-from-ukraine-still-traumatized-by-war/2527213) first hand accounts of Turkish students escaping from Ukraine via Romania, so it's not implausible that  Indian and Turkish students may have shared a bus at one point etc. Turkey also established a field hospital on the Romanian side of the border (at Siret). That particular Turkish student doesn't mention any interaction with Indians though, and says she escaped by train (which came under fire, and then she had to walk).

Comment: https://www.dw.com/en/india-fake-news-problem-fueled-by-digital-illiteracy/a-56746776

Answer (score 1):

There have been some reports of [discrimination](https://time.com/6153276/ukraine-refugees-racism/) when foreign residents of Ukraine tried to flee. Part of that was bureaucratic oversight -- Ukrainian citizens can enter visa-free for 90 days, so all that was required was relaxing the rule regarding biometric passports. The blanket permission has been clarified now to include all residents of Ukraine, whatever their citizenship. But part of that seems to be racist discrimination on the part of some Eastern European border officials.

So Pakistani students might well have **thought** that Indians would find a warmer welcome in those eastern EU countries.

Comment: From what I've seen reported the discrimination was largely on the Ukrainian side, and mostly based on skin color, so India vs Pakistan flags wouldn't have helped much with that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQvw2EcGoiY

Comment: Oh, and a bit of that in Poland too, but not by officials https://www.bbc.com/news/live/world-europe-60532634?ns_mchannel=social&ns_source=twitter&ns_campaign=bbc_live&ns_linkname=62217a6c0ce87e491a0edfb5%26Polish%20%27ultra%27%20fans%20intimidate%20BBC%20Africa%20reporters%20in%20migrant%20arrival%20town%262022-03-04T14%3A54%3A22.232Z&ns_fee=0&pinned_post_locator=urn:asset:3661fa0f-57de-4431-93e1-9721491aeb76&pinned_post_asset_id=62217a6c0ce87e491a0edfb5&pinned_post_type=share

Answer (score -1):

**Note:** Personally, I never consult news from Indian media if they post something on Pakistan and its allies.

Fake news takes place in all countries around the world. However, the difference in the case of India is, mainstream media is involved in the spread of fake news.

- [Five Times Zee News Was Caught Spreading Lies](https://thelogicalindian.com/news/zee-news-producing-fake-news-segments-21003)
- [ANI caught spreading fake news on Tablighi Jamaat, news agency faces social media roasting after Noida Police’s public admonishing](https://www.jantakareporter.com/india/ani-caught-spreading-fake-news-on-tablighi-jamaat-news-agency-faces-social-media-roasting-after-noida-polices-extraordinary-tweet/287014/)
- [Indian Chronicles: Deep Dive Into A 15-year Operation Targeting The Eu And Un To Serve Indian Interests](https://www.disinfo.eu/publications/indian-chronicles-deep-dive-into-a-15-year-operation-targeting-the-eu-and-un-to-serve-indian-interests/)

---

This question is flawed at its core.

> Why are Pakistani and Turkish students pretending to be Indians to flee Ukraine?
> There are reports of Pakistani and Turkish students using the Indian Flag to flee out of the war in Ukraine.

Were they pretending or did they find an Indian group of students with an Indian flag and decided to join them?

**N.B. 25% of the foreign students studying in Ukraine were from India.**

> Why are they not able to use the flags of their native countries to flee out of Ukraine?

**Firstly**, I am not sure if they tried to use their flags or not. Coz, the situation was so intense that there was no room for nationalistic experimentations.

To me, the most possible thing that happened to them was, they found Indian caravans on their way and they just hopped in. And, then, as usual, Indian media and propaganda machinery vehemently started propagating this news as **both Pakistan and Turkey are India's political adversaries**.

**Secondly**, the honest answer to this question would be, Muslims are supposed to face discrimination, racism, and possibly physical attack in an Eastern European Slavic country because of historical reasons and because of religious prejudice.

Comment: It seems this answer has a bias against India. Fake news is global pandemic,  a couple of reports about Fake news in Pakistan --> https://www.thenews.com.pk/print/604353-fake-news-a-conundrum-that-demands-serious-discourse-in-pakistan and https://nhrf.no/article/2020/sifting-truths-from-lies-in-the-age-of-fake-news

Comment: It's also not a good answer because it begins with soapboxing about a topic that's only tangential related to the question (trustworthiness of Indian media). But then it does not even attempt to disprove the sources in the question by providing any more reliable sources of information. It instead resorts to wild speculation and guessing what *could* have happened instead, making the claims in this answer appear even less trustworthy than the claims in the question. Simply presenting an alternative hypothesis and not backing it up by anything is how to do proper fact-checking.